# XSL:FO how to 'flow' info separate from body into xsl-region-start and xsl-region-end

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, tei

I have a medieval manuscript encoded in XML (using TEI schema). The manuscript has a 'body' which has been mapped in XSL:FO to `xsl-region-body` and outputs perfectly. The manuscript also features some 'glosses' (notes) in the left and right margins. These are marked up within the XML document using, for example `<add type="margin_gloss" place="left">Some foo note</add>`

I have reserved `xsl-region-start`and `xsl-region-end` to receive these margin glosses relative to their position in the original manuscript. However I am having trouble getting the marked up text to 'flow' into these regions.

Note: I have no problem putting hardcoded data into these regions with, for example, `<fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">`

The problem is that with the below code Apache FOP is telling me : `For "fo:page-sequence", only one "fo:flow" may be declared.`

```
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="odd">
            <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after"
                font-family="Times"
                font-size="8pt">
                <fo:block text-align="center">-<fo:page-number/>-
                </fo:block>
            </fo:static-content>
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-end"
                font-family="Times"
                font-size="6pt">
                <xsl:call-template name="marginalia-right"/>
            </fo:flow>
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" 
                font-family="Times"
                font-size="8pt"
                space-before="8pt"
                space-after="8pt">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
```

I extract the notes with an XSL template:

```
 <xsl:template match="//tei:add[@type='margin_gloss' and @place='right']" name="marginalia-right">
      <fo:block>
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
      </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>
```

To summarize the problem: I would like the margin glosses marked up in XML  with `<add>` to appear in `xsl-region-start` and `xsl-region-end` positioned relative to line of text in `xsl-region-body`. FPO tells me I can't 'flow' twice.

Comment: Perhaps I need to use an alternate structure, like `xsl-fo tables` with 3 columns? The main content (the body) breaks naturally into paragraphs which visually would work within table 'cells'. That is to say...I'm open to rethinking the approach in `xsl-fo`.

Comment: Why is float-left and float-right not working? Like marginalia ... see this example http://www.renderx.com/usecasestest.html and Marginalia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't synchronize content in region-start with content in region-body.

You can, however, place content in region-body and manipulate its position so it overlaps the region-start. XSL-FO [provides](https://www.webucator.com/tutorial/learn-xsl-fo/footnotes-floats/floats-reading.cfm) the [fo:float](http://www.datypic.com/sc/fo11/e-fo_float.html) mechanism to do this.

```
<fo:block --extra wide and a negative left margin to overlap the region-start>
    <fo:float> this contains the margin note</fo:float>
    <fo:block>this contains the body text linked to the note</fo:block>
</fo:block>
```

FOP has [limited support](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/fo.html#floats) for fo:float. Commercial FO processors (I use Antennahouse Formatter) offer full support.

Comment: @kevin-brown thanks both. I'm trying to work out fo:float now. I may need to make a new post about this. In principle I should use a template like this to insert the float? `<xsl:template match="//tei:add[@type='margin_gloss' and @place='right']">
      <fo:float float="right"><fo:block><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></fo:block></fo:float>
  </xsl:template>`

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: I've worked on this for some time with no success, posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47934126/xslfo-float-for-displaying-margin-notes-breaks-document