# XSL:FO float for displaying margin notes - breaks document

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, tei

I have a large medieval manuscript transcribed into XML (using TEI schema). I am using xsl:fo and Apache FOP to process into PDF. The file is constructed using nested `<body>`, `<p>`, `<seg>` as shown below. Occasionally `<add>` is used for margin notes.

```
<body>
   <p>
    <title>title here</title>
    <seg>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        Quisque a orci non mauris convallis imperdiet consequat nec 
        purus. Cras mollis lacus vel lectus facilisis, non
        hendrerit velit tempor. Phasellus tempor urna vel accumsan 
        dignissim.</seg>
    <seg>Aliquam porta eu nunc sed laoreet. 
        Sed<add type='margin_gloss'>Some margin note here</add> 
        non nulla consectetur, lobortis tortor ac,
        placerat nunc. Nulla viverra finibus est nec efficitur. Donec 
        nisi nisl, tincidunt dapibus purus pretium, rhoncus volutpat 
        tortor. Cras fringilla tellus tortor, at
        ultricies mi cursus at. Nulla facilisi.</seg>
    <seg>Quisque id mi nisl. In in mauris id leo malesuada hendrerit. 
        Orci varius natoque
        penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus 
        mus. Nulla sit amet
        commodo mauris.</seg>
  </p>
</body>
```

The xml file is massive, and so there is one master xml file which uses `<xi:include>`s to bring hundreds of these documents in order to compose the complete manuscript.

I have successfully processed this into a PDF with the following basic instructions:

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <fo:root>
         <fo:layout-master-set>
             <fo:simple-page-master 
                master-name="page-recto"
                page-height="29.7cm"  page-width="21cm"
                margin-top="2cm" margin-bottom="2cm" 
                margin-left="2cm" margin-right="1cm">
                <fo:region-body 
                    region-name="xsl-region-body"/>
             </fo:simple-page-master>
         </fo:layout-master-set>

        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="page-recto">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" 
                font-family="Times" font-weight="normal" 
                font-size="8pt" space-before="8pt" space-after="8pt"
                text-align="justify" end-indent="120pt">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>

     </fo:root>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="body/p">
     <fo:block 
         page-break-inside="avoid"
         font-size="9pt" font-weight="bold" 
         padding-bottom="1cm" end-indent="120pt">
         <xsl:value-of select="tei:title"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </fo:block>
   </xsl:template>


   <xsl:template match="seg">
      <fo:block id="@xml:id"
          font-family="Times" font-weight="normal"
         font-size="8pt" space-before="8pt"
         space-after="8pt" text-align="justify"
         end-indent="120pt">
             <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>
```

This gives me a successful result like this page:

[image: Successful sample]

I've indented the right side (end) in order to make room for the margin notes. For example, in the 4th `<seg>` of the first `<p>`, there is a margin note 'Fabri +'. It is encoded `<add type=margin_gloss>Fabri +</add>`

I add the following template to 'float' the margin gloss:

```
<xsl:template match="body/p//add[@type='margin_gloss']">
     <fo:float float="end">
            <fo:block-container>
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:value-of select="./s/text()"/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
        </fo:float>

</xsl:template>
```

And I get this disaster (the red text/arrows are my guides to the problems). The template with float has done 3 things which I cannot fathom. The float 'should' appear beside the 4th segment, but instead is below, merged with the next `<p>`; the 4th `<seg>` has disappeared; and the following `<p>`'s indent is reduced.

[image: 3 disasters with one template]

Comment: Float should be right not end to put it on the right.

Comment: @KevinBrown I tried that, it made a 2 cm difference only to the indent - it did not return the missing segment, nor float the marginalia towards the margin.

Comment: Your template has ./s/text() and there is no element s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, not an answer for you because you are using FOP and it has very limited support for floats. I took you example, expanded it a bit with content and removed some strange things like setting the ID as you did.

This XML:

```
<body>
<p>
    <title>title here</title>
    <seg>1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        Quisque a orci non mauris convallis imperdiet consequat nec 
        purus. Cras mollis lacus vel lectus facilisis, non
        hendrerit velit tempor. Phasellus tempor urna vel accumsan 
        dignissim.</seg>
    <seg>2 note Aliquam porta eu nunc sed laoreet. 
        Sed<add type='margin_gloss'>Some margin note here</add> 
        non nulla consectetur, lobortis tortor ac,
        placerat nunc. Nulla viverra finibus est nec efficitur. Donec 
        nisi nisl, tincidunt dapibus purus pretium, rhoncus volutpat 
        tortor. Cras fringilla tellus tortor, at
        ultricies mi cursus at. Nulla facilisi.</seg>
    <seg>3 Quisque id mi nisl. In in mauris id leo malesuada hendrerit. 
        Orci varius natoque
        penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus 
        mus. Nulla sit amet
        commodo mauris.</seg>
    <seg>4 Quisque id mi nisl. In in mauris id leo malesuada hendrerit. 
        Orci varius natoque
        penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus 
        mus. Nulla sit amet
        commodo mauris.</seg>
    <seg>5 Quisque id mi nisl. In in mauris id leo malesuada hendrerit. 
        Orci varius natoque
        penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus 
        mus. Nulla sit amet
        commodo mauris.</seg>
    <seg>6 note Aliquam porta eu nunc sed laoreet. 
        Sed<add type='margin_gloss'>Some margin note here 2</add> 
        non nulla consectetur, lobortis tortor ac,
        placerat nunc. Nulla viverra finibus est nec efficitur. Donec 
        nisi nisl, tincidunt dapibus purus pretium, rhoncus volutpat 
        tortor. Cras fringilla tellus tortor, at
        ultricies mi cursus at. Nulla facilisi.</seg>
    <seg>7 Quisque id mi nisl. In in mauris id leo malesuada hendrerit. 
        Orci varius natoque
        penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus 
        mus. Nulla sit amet
        commodo mauris.</seg>
    <seg>8 Quisque id mi nisl. In in mauris id leo malesuada hendrerit. 
        Orci varius natoque
        penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus 
        mus. Nulla sit amet
        commodo mauris.</seg>
</p>
</body>
```

Processed with this XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" 
version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root>
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master 
                master-name="page-recto"
                page-height="29.7cm"  page-width="21cm"
                margin-top="2cm" margin-bottom="2cm" 
                margin-left="2cm" margin-right="1cm">
                <fo:region-body 
                    region-name="xsl-region-body"/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>

        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="page-recto">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" 
                font-family="Times" font-weight="normal" 
                font-size="8pt" space-before="8pt" space-after="8pt"
                text-align="justify" end-indent="120pt">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>

    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="body/p">
    <fo:block 
        page-break-inside="avoid"
        font-size="9pt" font-weight="bold" 
        padding-bottom="1cm" end-indent="120pt">
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="add">
    <fo:inline font-style="italic">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:inline>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="seg">
    <fo:block
        font-family="Times" font-weight="normal"
        font-size="8pt" space-before="8pt"
        space-after="8pt" text-align="justify"
        end-indent="2.5in">
        <xsl:if test="descendant::add[@type='margin_gloss']">
            <fo:float float="right">
                <fo:block-container width="2in" border="1pt solid black" margin="10pt">
                    <fo:block>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="add[@type='margin_gloss']"/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:block-container>
            </fo:float>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Results in this PDF **when using RenderX XEP** showing your floating Notes. If I use Apache FOP 2.1, they are totally missing as are the paragraphs that have the float in them. This totally indicates to me that FOP does not support this float, you should contact them for support.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I suspected as much, and I have looked longingly at RenderX this past week...but as an academic it's outside my price range.

Comment: Academic use is free, just send in a request. http://www.renderx.com/download/academic.html

Comment: Outstanding. Thanks very much Kevin.

Comment: I've installed RenderX and your sample works perfectly,
 thanks again. However, I don't understand the interaction of templates in your code. You've used `<xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>` near the end of `<xsl:template match="seg">`instead of `<xsl:apply-templates>`?

Comment: To clarify the intent of my question: `<xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>` seems to 'stop dead' the effect of other templates acting on the same `<seg>` (ie. in my live xml file there is more processing to follow within the `<seg>`).

Comment: Then add their templates. Or select all things other then than pull quotes in a template.

Comment: I've got RenderX working well now but have struggled with one formatting piece of this marginalia. I've posted a [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48005073/xsl-or-xslfo-interaction-of-two-templates-during-formatting), perhaps you can take a look. Thanks.